# In react, how to target specific table row with onChange event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have table that contains multiple rows and has a dropdown for the last column on each row which contains 3 values **Incomplete**, **Fail**, and **Pass**. If the dropdown is selected to Pass then I need to show checkmark icon, and if the dropdown is selected to Fail, then bug icon would show up.

The above logic seems to be working fine. What I am struggling with is how do I target the specific row of the table only and not have any affect on the other rows. I only want to show the icon to the row that I am targeting (in this example, row 1).

For example, this is what my current table looks like. It's affecting both of the rows:
[image]

Likewise for the other Fail option:

[image]

Here's what my code looks like:

```
this.state = {
    ...
    test_steps: [],
  status: ""
};

selectStatus(e) {
  var selected = $('.status_list option:selected').text();
  if(selected == "Pass") {
      this.setState({status: e.target.value})
      $('.checkmark').show();
      $('.bug').hide();
      $(".checkmark").css({"display": "inline", "marginLeft": "10px"});
  } else if(selected == "Fail") {
      this.setState({status: e.target.value})
      $('.bug').show();
      $('.checkmark').hide();
      $(".bug").css({"display": "inline", "marginLeft": "10px"});
  } else {
      this.setState({status: e.target.value})
      $('.checkmark').hide();
      $('.bug').hide();
  }
}

tsteps = test_steps.map((testStep, index) => {
  return (
  <tr key={index}>
      <td>{testStep.step_number}</td>
      <td>{testStep.description}</td>
      <td>{testStep.expected_results}</td>
      <td>{testStep.other_info}</td>
      <td>
          <select 
            className="status_list form-control" 
            id="status" 
            onChange={this.selectStatus.bind(this)} // calling selectStatus function
          >
            <option className={styles.emptyVal}></option>
            <option>Incomplete</option>
            <option>Fail</option>
            <option>Pass</option>
          </select>
          <div className="checkmark" style={{display: 'none'}}>
              <i className={`fas fa-check ${styles.check_icon}`}></i>
          </div>
          <div className="bug" style={{display: 'none'}}>
              <i className={`fas fa-bug ${styles.bug_icon}`}></i>
          </div>
          {testStep.status}
      </td>
  </tr>
  );
});
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
this.state = {
  test_steps: [],
  status: []
};

selectStatus(event, index) {
  this.setState(oldState => {
    const newStatus = oldState.status.slice();
    newStatus[index] = event.target.value;
    return {
      status: newStatus
    };
  });
};

tsteps = test_steps.map((testStep, index) => {
  return (
  <tr key={index}>
      <td>{testStep.step_number}</td>
      <td>{testStep.description}</td>
      <td>{testStep.expected_results}</td>
      <td>{testStep.other_info}</td>
      <td>
          <select
              className="status_list form-control" 
              value={this.state.status[index]}
              onChange={e => this.selectStatus(e, index)} >
              <option className={styles.emptyVal}></option>
              <option>Incomplete</option>
              <option>Fail</option>
              <option>Pass</option>
            </select>
          {this.state.status[index] === "Pass" && 
              <div className="checkmark">
                <i className={`fas fa-check ${styles.check_icon}`}></i>
              </div>
            }
            {this.state.status[index] === "Fail" && 
              <div className="bug">
                <i className={`fas fa-bug${styles.bug_icon}`}></i>
              </div>
            }        
            {testStep.status}
      </td>
  </tr>
  );
});
```

**Error that I am getting:**
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using jquery to manually alter the dom. React has no idea that you're doing that, and so you will create bugs by making it impossible for react to reconcile the dom correctly.

Instead, you should be using react's component state, and then rendering what you want based on that state. You already are using state to track the steps, you just need to add in the status, and then render using that. So augment your state to be something like this:

```
this.state = {
    ...
    test_steps: [],
    status: [] <--- now an array
};
```

And then when you render, do something like this:

```
test_steps.map((testStep, index) => {
  return (
    <tr key={index}>
      // some components omitted
      <select
        className="status_list form-control" 
        value={this.state.status[index]} <-- now taken from state
        onChange={e => this.selectStatus(e, index)} >
        // options omitted
      </select>
      {this.state.status[index] === "Pass" && 
        <div className="checkmark">
          <i className={`fas fa-check ${styles.check_icon}`}></i>
        </div>
      }
      {this.state.status[index] === "Fail" && 
        <div className="bug">
          <i className={`fas fa-bug${styles.bug_icon}`}></i>
        </div>
      }        
      {testStep.status}
    </tr>
  );
});
```

In the above code i made selectStatus expect an index, and so here's how selectStatus would use that:

```
selectStatus(event, index) {
  this.setState(oldState => {
    const newStatus = oldState.status.slice();
    newStatus[index] = event.target.value;
    return {
      status: newStatus
    };
  });
};
```

---

EDIT: to fix the null error there are two options. First, we can synchronously save the value we care about, so it will be available when the async code runs

```
selectStatus(event, index) {
 const val = event.target.value;
 this.setState(oldState => {
    const newStatus = oldState.status.slice();
    newStatus[index] = val;
    return {
      status: newStatus
    };
  });
};
```

or we can tell react to save the event object, rather than reusing it.

```
selectStatus(event, index) {
  event.persist();
  this.setState(oldState => {
    const newStatus = oldState.status.slice();
    newStatus[index] = event.target.value;
    return {
      status: newStatus
    };
  });
};
```

Comment: Nicholas, thank you so much for the response. I have updated my post with updated code as you suggested. Can you please take a look at it again? I am running into `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` error. I am not sure why.

Comment: The issue is that i had you use event.target.value inside the callback function of setState. React's synthetic events nulls out its properties after synchronous code has finished executing, which causes a problem when doing async stuff (see https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling). I've edited my response to include two possible fixes.

Comment: Thank you for providing explanation along with two fixes. This will help me in my learning with React. I tried both of the fixes you mentioned, and they both throw the following error: `Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string 'Active'`. Do you know the fix for this?

Comment: apparently some bit of code is trying to assign to an element of a string. Of the code you've shown, the only spot that *might* be doing that is `newStatus[index] = val`, but i don't see how since newStatus should be an array, not a string. The error message may include a line number, or if it doesn't you can use breakpoints and console.log statements to find where the problem is. Once you find the spot where you're trying to assign to a string, either fix it so it isn't a string (if the type is wrong), or fix it so you aren't assigning to it (if the operation is wrong)

Comment: You were right! I had status wriiten somewhere in the code where it was assigning to the string value. Once I removed that code, the issue is gone and I can see the icon appearing on the row that I target now. Thank you so much Nicholas from the bottom of my heart! I was struggling with this issue since yesterday and your help really means a lot! I really appreciate your time and support in helping me with this!